# Create script to login and change time on unix Darwin

Tags: script, date-time, x-server, darwin

I work for a non-profit and recently had to take on some sysadmin responsibilities, and and it is a new area for me.

We have a Apple X Server that is running Darwin, and from time to time, especially on reboots, the timer on it gets out of sync which causes the machine to be unaccessible via share. I would like to write a little script that i can run that logs-in, updates the time, and logs out.

The main reason I would like to do it this way, is so that I can share that script user/pw with other non-technical folk. Currently, I login as root "Administrator" and type the following, "date MMddHHmmYY" (substituting the values MMddHHmmYY with the current date/time) and the problem resolves the issue.

I have read that only the root can change the date on the box, is it possible to create a user who logs in as root, changes time, logs out, without giving the root user info away?

I have not written a script before, and don't really know where to start. If you can point me in the right places, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write a script for this. The following command will do the job:

```
   ssh root@AppleXServer 'date MMddHHmmYY'
```

This command, issued from any pc capable of reaching AppleXServer, executes the command within apostrophes as the user who is logging into the machine, in this case `root`.

However, for this to work you *must* have root credentials, there is no way around that.